# Difference in instantiating a Class in Python

Tags: python, class, kivy

I am currently working on a introductory project for kivy. I got an error while trying to understand the concept by playing around with the codes. I would like to know what is the difference between the 2 codes below. Thank you.

**Orginal:**

sm = WindowManager(),

sm.current = "second"

**Current:**

WindowsManager().current = "second"

Answer (score 0):

method 1: you create a WindowManager instance and call it sm, then you assign the attribute current with "second".

method 2: you create a temp WindowManager instance and assign the attribute current with "second". Then the temp instance will be removed by garbage collection. (i.e. nothing really happens.)